# Mailgun & CfMailGun component. How to implement it

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I'm trying to use the component [https://github.com/DominicWatson/cfmailgun][1] to send email (using `SendMessage ()`) through mailgun. 
I am not able to use it. I have read the documentation at this address: **http://dominicwatson.github.io/cfmailgun/**

But I can not implement it. The author has not included a complete example.

He added only this:

```
mailGunClient = new MailGunClient( apiKey = myPrivateApiKey );
```

Can anyone help me with a more complete example? 
Thank you.

---

**Edit:**
After some tests, I've tried with:

```
<cfscript>
    myPrivateApiKey = "key-123456789";
    mailGunClient   = new MailGunClient( apiKey = myPrivateApiKey );

    mailGunClient.sendMessage(domain = 'domain.com', from='info@domain.com', to='to@gmail.com', subject='Test', text='hello world', html='<b>hello world</b>');
</cfscript>
```

But I get the error:

> `MailGun request failure. ['from' parameter is missing]`

---

**Edit 2**
I solved it *(thanks to the help of the author of the script)*. It was a problem in the component.
Anywhere you see `<cfhttpparam ... name="#key#" ...`, changing that to `<cfhttpparam ... name="#LCase( key )#" ...`

Comment: that's not the example given on that page, I think you mean `mailGunClient = new MailGunClient( apiKey = myPrivateApiKey );`

Comment: you should then be able to use it simply like `ID = mailGunClient.SendMessage(domain = 'foo', from='example@example.com', to='example@example.com', subject='test', text='hello world' html='<b>hello world</b>');`

Comment: @duncan: Hello duncan. thanks, but I still do not understand... I'm not an expert in cfml. Can you give me a complete sample? Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible you got your code mixed up? Because I do not see how the code above could generate that error.. since clearly the `from` parameter was supplied. Can you post the *complete* error message along with the *exact* code that generated it?

Comment: Ivan - Glad you figured it out. You should post that as an "answer" so it is more visible (Plus others can vote on it too).